# Properties inherited by the inverse function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, elliptic-operators

I'm doing research about some model arising in electromagnetism and there is a function, let us denote it
$$\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \mathbf{g}(\nabla u) = \nu(|\nabla u|)\nabla u,$$
where $u:\Omega\times[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ is the solution to said electromagnetism model, $\Omega$ is a bounded open Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\nu:\mathbb{R}_0^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ is a $C^1$ function such that $\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}) := \nu(|\mathbf{x}|)\mathbf{x}$ satisfies the following properties:
$$|\mathbf{g}_i(\mathbf{x})| \leq C_1\|\mathbf{x}\|_{\mathbb{R}^2}, \qquad \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\mathbf{g}_i(\mathbf{x})\right|\leq C_1 \quad \forall i,j\in\{1,2\}$$
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\mathbf{g}_i(\mathbf{x})y_iy_j \geq C_2\|\mathbf{y}\|^2_{\mathbb{R}^2}.$$

I know that, in virtue of the implicit function theorem, the ellipticity condicion above guarantees that the relation $\boldsymbol{\lambda} = \nu(|\nabla u|)\nabla u$
can be inverted to obtain $\nabla u$ as a function of $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$, say
$$\nabla u = \boldsymbol{\psi}(\boldsymbol{\lambda}).$$

Basically, we obtain the inverse function $\boldsymbol{\psi}$ og $\mathbf{g}$. What I would like to ask you is: there is any possible way to prove that this inverse function inherits the properties that I mentioned above are satisfied by $\mathbf{g}$? I've seen some particular cases in which that is true, so I've tried to prove it myself but I just simply don't even know how to even start and I haven't been able to find references about this subject either.

If anyone can give me some hints or references about this I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question it can be restated as follows:  you want to compute the second-order Taylor expansion of a multivariable inverse map.
That is, given  a column vector  of functions $ \vec y(x)$ whose Taylor expansion up to second order is known  at each point,   find the
corresponding expansion for the inverse function $\vec x(\vec y)$. This can be computed by implicit differentiation but it's a pain. The method outlined below just requires that we make some simple-minded algebraic substitutions, so no calculus is involved. (The calculus is swept under the rug, so to speak.)

The key idea is that the one-variable example $ y= e^x = 1 + x+ \frac{x^2}{2} +\dots$ and its inverse relation $x= \ln (y) = (y-1) -\frac{1}{2} (y-1)^2 +\ldots$ in which the quadratic terms have **reversed signs** generalizes to the multivariable setting.  Here are the gory details.

The first-order expansion of $y$ in terms of $x$, written in matrix notation,  starts off as
$ [y] \approx [L][x]$ where square brackets denote matrices ( and $[L]$ is the Jacobian matrix of first-order partials evaluated at the point of expansion).

The second-order expansion  $ \vec y= [L (\vec x)] + [Q(\vec x)] +\ldots$ is  a sum of linear and quadratic terms.

It is helpful to create new auxiliary variables $[u]$ defined by the linear change of variables $[x]= [L]^{-1} [u]$. (Here $L$ is a constant matrix, the Jacobian matrix with entries frozen). This substitution is done so that   $ [y]\approx [u]$ is correct up to second-order terms that will be dealt with next. That is, in these new variables we appear to be working with a transformation that is close to the identity map. This trick simplifies many things.

Then write the column vector $[Q(x)]$ as a matrix product of a square matrix and a column vector, as $[Q(x)]= [q_1(x)| q_2(x)| q_3(x), \ldots ] [x]$ where the lower-case $q_i(x)$ are  column vectors (typeset as separated by vertical bars) forming  a square  matrix, each of whose entries is a first-order (linear) function of $x$. Recapping,  the matrix product $[Q]=[q_1(x), q_2(x), ] [x]$ is a column vector whose entries are each quadratic scalar functions in $x$.

Write this all in terms of $[u]$ instead:

$y= [u]+ [ q_1(x(u))| q_2(x(u)), | \ldots ] [L^{-1}] u$

$$y= [u]+ [ \tilde q_1(u))| \tilde q_2(u), | \ldots  ] [L^{-1}] u$$

where $\tilde q_i (x[u])= q_i(L^{-1}(u))$ is simply the result of expressing each $x$ in terms of $u$ in every scalar function in every column.

**The inverse quadratic Taylor expansion**

We claim that the quadratic Taylor expansion of the inverse functional relation  that solve for $u$ in terms of $y$ is structurally identical to the preceding by swapping the letters $u$ and $y$ everywhere but **you reverse the signs in the quadratic terms:**

$$[u]= [y]- [ \tilde q_1((y)))| \tilde q_2(y), | ] [L^{-1}] [y]$$

Finally,  you wish to switch from $u$ to your original variables and solve for $x$ by making the substitution $ [x]= [L]^{-1} [u]$. That is, multiply from the left the previous equation by the constant matrix $[L^{-1}]$.

**Verification of the claim.**

Try composing $y= u + [q(u)][u]$ with the substitution  $ u(y)= y- [q(y)][y]$ and see if you get the identity map to the correct order.

$y=?= ( y - [q(y)][y] + q[u(y)][u(y)] $

$y=?= ( y - [q(y)][y] + q[y- \ldots ][y- \ldots]$ is correct  up to terms  of third-order or higher,  which arise when you include the suppressed terms of second-order denoted by the ellipses ($\ldots$).

I suggest working some simple explicit one-variable and two-variable examples by hand and checking that all the steps work out as claimed.  (It is a pain to typeset all the numerical details but I hope these pointers will get you started.)

P.S. This related post [inverse function power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651676/inverse-of-multivariate-function-power-series/4652203#4652203) provides a method for getting the Taylor expansions of arbitrarily high order by a recursive algorithm. It also shows an explicit numerical example.